# Page need refresh to use updated cookies

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the following procedure:

- Button that calls function `fcn1` and href to some page `p1`
- fcn1 reads 6 strings from backend SQL
- The 6 strings are stored in cookies
- Page `p1` read the 6 cookies and display the resulint 6 strings

Above works fine - The problem is that p1 needs a refresh before showing the newest 6 strings. The cookies are fine - I can see that under "Cookies" in "inspect". I have tried to put in `pause(x);` and `location.reload()` on `p1`.

How do i make sure that the cookies are set by the functions, before the php builds the HTML?

One solution could be to make another ajax, updating the 6 strings on `p1`, but i dont like that solution - Seems like one to many steps.
I can't post all the code since it's several hundres lines in total.
Below is the button that calls functions and href (it runs in a for loop with index `j`):

```
echo '<span><li><a onclick="fcn1('.$games_id[$j].')" href="/cc/p1.php" id="'.$games_id[$j]. '" value='.$games_id[$j]. '>' .$games_text[$j]. '</a></li></span>';
```

Below is how the text is defined in p1, where it seems to load and "old cookie".

```
<text x="501" y="289.9721" alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-family="Verdana" font-size="24"><?php echo $_COOKIE["cat1_str"] ?></text>
```

Thanks

Update 1:

```
<script>
function fcn1(game) {
    var gameid = game;
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(+ date + (30 * 86400000)); // Cookie expires in 30 days
    document.cookie = "SelectedGame=" + gameid + "; expires=" + date.toGMTString() + "; path=/";
    SetStandardGameCategories();
}
</script>

<script language="javascript">
    function SetStandardGameCategories() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/content/SetStandardGameServer.php",
            data: {},
            success: function(data){ 
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

SetStandardGameServer.php

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    require("db.php");

    if(isset($_COOKIE['SelectedGame'])) {
        SaveStandardCategories($_COOKIE['SelectedGame']);
    }
?>
```

Comment: You need to redirect in a callback function in your ajax. Show us `fcn1` function and I'll show you how

Comment: Cookies are sent with the page, if you are not refreshing the page you wont get the new cookies.

Comment: Instead of generated the html using PHP in refresh try to update using the javascript DOM manipulation.

Comment: @RiggsFolly How do I refresh the page after the new cookies are sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait for the PHP execution and then redirect.

```
echo '<span><li><a onclick="fcn1('.$games_id[$j].', \'/cc/p1.php\'); return false;" href="#" id="'.$games_id[$j]. '" value='.$games_id[$j]. '>' .$games_text[$j]. '</a></li></span>';
```

Script:

```
function fcn1(game, redirectURL) {
    var gameid = game;
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(+ date + (30 * 86400000)); // Cookie expires in 30 days
    document.cookie = "SelectedGame=" + gameid + "; expires=" + date.toGMTString() + "; path=/";
    SetStandardGameCategories(redirectURL);
}

function SetStandardGameCategories(redirectURL) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/content/SetStandardGameServer.php",
        data: {},
        success: function(data){
            if (redirectURL) {
                window.location.href = redirectURL;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Notice that I have added a new parameter. If you are using this function in other places and you don't want to redirect, just leave the parameter empty.